# How to read-in date with improperly taken data

Tags: r, date

I'm using the data from this link: http://lib.stat.cmu.edu/datasets/csb/ch14.dat, and the column of interest are the 2nd and the 15th. I'm working with R.
These are dates, and I'm trying to find the time lapsed between these two. However they aren't entered as dates (like 5-15-2019), they look like character strings to the program. Which function in R do I use to parse these and get a new column that tells me the amount time between these dates?

Comment: We can follow your question as it is now, but it would be best to edit it, and include as text some sample data from you input file.  External links can, and often do, break over time, which would leave your question in an unusable state.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Months are represented as single-digit month, we need to change it to double digit by padding zero. One way to do that is using `sprintf`, after that we convert the data to dates and subtract them.

```
df <- read.table("http://lib.stat.cmu.edu/datasets/csb/ch14.dat")
df$Diff_in_days <- as.Date(sprintf("%06d", df$V15), "%m%d%y") - 
                   as.Date(sprintf("%06d", df$V2), "%m%d%y")

head(df[15:20])
#     V15 V16 V17 V18 V19 Diff_in_days
#1  72984   D   N   .   Y       6 days
#2  82184   D   N   .   Y      33 days
#3  82585   D   N   .   Y     361 days
#4  10286   D   N   .   Y     488 days
#5 111485   D   N   .   Y     350 days
#6 112686   D   N   .   Y     721 days
```

You might want to wrap `as.numeric` to get actual numbers in `Diff_in_days`.

---

Another option is to use `lubridate`s `mdy` function which handles this automatically.

```
library(lubridate)
df$Diff_in_days <- mdy(df$V15) - mdy(df$V2)
```

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know about the `sprintf` function, that'll help me out.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that your two date columns be in the format `monthdayyear`, with a two digit year, you may try using `as.Date` with the format mask `%m%d%%y`:

```
dates <- c("072384", "072984")
dt <- as.Date(dates, format = "%m%d%y")
dt

[1] "1984-07-23" "1984-07-29"
```